# WPF Scrollviewer MouseUp

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a control that has a `ScrollViewer` and in the `ScrollViewer` there is an `Image` control, what I would like to do is when my `ScrollViewer` reaches the bottom (see code) I would like to switch to the next `Image`.

```
    private void ImageScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;
  if (!_hasChangedDueToScroll)
  {
    if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight && scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight != 0.0)
    {
      if (_pageNo != _maxPageNo - 1)
      {
        ChangePage(_pageNo + 1);
        _hasChangedDueToScroll = true;
        scrollViewer.ScrollToTop();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thing is, the `_hasChangedDueToScroll` needs to be there so that the code does not just run through all images to the last one, so I want to change `_hasChangedDueToScroll` when the mouse button is up from the `ScrollViewer`, but even if i add an event for `MouseUp`, the event never executes.

Any ideas why that might be?

Thank you

Comment: Try handling the `PreviewMouseUp` tunneling event instead.

Comment: @Sheridan did try that as well with no luck

Comment: have you tried adding a boolean for handled events as well ?

AddHandler(CrapEvent..,OnCrap..,true);

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that the `MouseDown` event is never fired either as you don't need to press any `Button` to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` instead of `MouseUp`